# On confirm delete?

Tags: ajax, mootools

i have this mootools code that on click of a button deletes the record,now i want when the user clicks the delete button a confirm dialog pop up asking am i sure that i want to delete the record with the answers yes and no...here is my code...if the user answers yes to continue this request if he answers no dont continue,it would be also great if i had another message saying that the record was deleted after he clicked yes...

```
<script>
window.addEvent('domready',function() {


$$('a.delete').each(function(el) {
el.addEvent('click',function(e) {
  e.stop();
  var parent = el.getParent('div');
  var request = new Request({
    url: '/delete.php',
    link: 'chain',
    method: 'get',
    data: {
      'delete': parent.get('id').replace('record-',''),
      ajax: 1
    },
    onRequest: function() {
      new Fx.Tween(parent,{
        duration:300
      }).start('background-color', '#fb6c6c');
    },
    onSuccess: function() {
      new Fx.Slide(parent,{
        duration:300,
        onComplete: function() {
          parent.dispose();
        }
      }).slideOut();
    }
  }).send();
});
 });

});


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's simple.

```
if (confirm('message')){ 
    // code when yes
}
else {
    // code when no
}
```

hence.

```
$$('a.delete').each(function (el) {
    el.addEvent('click', function (e) {
        e.stop();
        var parent = el.getParent('div');
        if (confirm('are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
            new Request({
                url: '/delete.php',
                link: 'chain',
                method: 'get',
                data: {
                    'delete': parent.get('id').replace('record-', ''),
                    ajax: 1
                },
                onRequest: function () {
                    new Fx.Tween(parent, {
                        duration: 300
                    }).start('background-color', '#fb6c6c');
                },
                onSuccess: function () {
                    new Fx.Slide(parent, {
                        duration: 300,
                        onComplete: function () {
                            parent.dispose();
                        }
                    }).slideOut();
                }
            }).send();
        } // confirm
    });
});
```